# Configurable product quantity not shown on invoice or order

Tags: magento

When a user purchase a configural product from my store, he goes to the checkout cart and in that it shows the basic details of the product and the price and quantity. After purchasing a configurable product, My cart looks something like this and also the invoice bottom and order bottom part looks the same as below

```
 Product Name Unit Price Qty Subtotal

Associate Support $825.00 1 $825.00

Hour
15
```

I want to add Quantity below Hour i.e.

```
Product Name Unit Price Qty Subtotal

Associate Support $825.00 1 $825.00

Hour
Quantity: 15
```

Can anyone please tell me how to add that text “Quantity” in My cart, in invoice and in order.

Comment: Where do you want to add this Text? Invoice Email or Invoice at admin ?

Comment: I would prefer in both

Answer (score 0):

For the Admin

Enable Template Path hints as follows

```
INSERT INTO `core_config_data` (`scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`)
       VALUES ('websites', '0', 'dev/debug/template_hints', '1');
```

Clear cache. With this enabled you would be able to know the templates/blocks in admin section

For FrontEnd
You can find templates for email here.You can follow the same path in your theme also

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/invoice
```

Comment: For frontEnd I tried as you mentioned. Inside the invoice folder, I found the code ie <th align="left" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px"><?php echo $this->__('Item') ?></th> I can't edit anything on this phtml file. inside 'Item' field I want the text "Quantity"